# Use Sharepoint Copy web service to copy folder and contents

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to make a program that copies all of a Sharepoint folder's contents (all subfolders and files) into another Sharepoint folder.  Both of these folders will be on the same Sharepoint site.

However, I am trying to do this remotely - if possible*.  Therefore, I have tried using the Copy web service without success.  The Copy web service appears to only work with copying files, not folders.  In addition, I cannot determine a way to iterate through the folder's contents to copy everything - it will only copy one item.

Thank you for any insights or tips,
  Scott

*From a custom CRM workflow activity

~~Edited for clarification~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I decided to create my own custom web service in Sharepoint that I was able to successfully access from Microsoft CRM.  If anyone is interested, I've pasted the C# code I used to copy the folder structure:

```
public String CopyFolderContents(String sourceURL, String folderURL, String destinationURL)
{
    try
    {
        #region Copying Code
        //Get the SPSite and SPWeb from the sourceURL
        using (SPWeb oWebsite = new SPSite(sourceURL).OpenWeb())
        {
            //Get the parent folder from the folderURL
            SPFolder oFolder = oWebsite.GetFolder(folderURL);

            //Create a list of all files (not folders) on the current level
            SPFileCollection collFile = oFolder.Files;

            //Copy all files on the current level to the target URL
            foreach (SPFile oFile in collFile)
            {
                oFile.CopyTo(destinationURL + "/" + oFile.Name, true);
            }
            //Create a list of all folders on the current level
            SPFolderCollection collFolder = oFolder.SubFolders;

            //Copy each of the folders and all of their contents
            String[] folderURLs = new String[collFolder.Count];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (SPFolder subFolder in collFolder)
            {
                folderURLs[i++] = subFolder.Url;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < folderURLs.Length; i++)
            {
                SPFolder folder = collFolder[folderURLs[i]];
                folder.CopyTo(destinationURL + "/" + folder.Name);
            }
        }
        #endregion Copying Code
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        #region Exception Handling
        String Message;
        if (e.InnerException != null)
            Message =  "MESSAGE: " + e.Message + "\n\n" +
                   "INNER EXCEPTION: " + e.InnerException.Message + "\n\n" +
                   "STACK TRACE: " + e.StackTrace + "\n\n" +
                   "Source: " + sourceURL + "\n" + 
                   "Folder: " + folderURL + "\n" +
                   "Destination: " + destinationURL; 
        else
            Message =  "MESSAGE: " + e.Message + "\n\n" +
                   "STACK TRACE: " + e.StackTrace + "\n\n" +
                   "Source: " + sourceURL + "\n" +
                   "Folder: " + folderURL + "\n" +
                   "Destination: " + destinationURL;
        throw new Exception(Message);
        #endregion Exception Handling
    }
    return "Operation Successful!";
}
```

All I did was add this method into a Sharepoint web service and called it from CRM and it works.

Thanks to everyone who provided other answers,
Scott

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple solution to this problem , as its just about copy and paste use the simple `XCOPY` command

**XCOPY** Copy files and/or directory trees to another folder. XCOPY is similar to the COPY command except that it has additional switches to specify both the source and destination in detail.

To copy a folder including all subfolders

```
 XCOPY C:\utils\* D:\Backup\utils /s /i
```

here /i defines the destination as a folder

for more detail please refer [this link](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)

Comment: Is there a way to trigger this from code as well as pass in parameters?  Also does this work with folders stored on a sharepoint server?

Comment: No. This doesn't answer your question at all.

Comment: @Paul-Jan - its about coping folder's contents ? is't it ?

Comment: Not DOS folders, SharePoint folders. They are not folders on disk, they are (*handwaving* more or less) SharePoint database entries served as virtual http folders. XCOPY only applies to folders on disk.